# Adding a trinket.io widget to a post

Tags: widgets, blog

I'm trying to add a [trinket.io](https://trinket.io/) widget to my blog post in order to do some interactive things but I'm not having any success.

If i try to just use the embed code given to me by the trinket.io page:

```
<iframe src="https://trinket.io/embed/python/73f4d9630f" width="100%" 
height="356" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

All i get is just a link to the widget like this:

https://trinket.io/embed/python/73f4d9630f

Is there any way to actually get the python code and its output onto the blog-post ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trinket.io founder here.  We embed trinkets in our Wordpress blog (blog.trinket.io) all the time, which is hosted by WPEngine (wpengine.com).  One solution is to use a hosting provider like WPEngine that works out of the box.  I have to imagine that many of the excellent independent hosing providers out there support iframe embeds out of the box.

If you're rolling your own wordpress instance, the open source Wordpress.org code allows for a domain whitelist of accepted automatic embeds.  More on modifying that [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#How_Can_I_Add_or_Change_Support_For_Websites.3F). It depends on whether the site supports oEmbed or not. Trinket.io currently does not, so follow the non-embed instructions.

If you'd like to explore the use of plugins, I haven't extensively researched these options but there's the [iframe](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/) plugin (as mentioned by Henrik Sommerland) and Embedly (wordpress.org/plugins/embedly/).  We're not an officially listed choice in Embedly but there's a built-in tool for embedding any URL- just put the trinket.io/embed/blah/blah URL in there and you'll be golden.

Sorry for the trouble!  These restrictions are put in place for security reasons so there's not much we can do to make your experience embedding Trinket.io content easier aside from suggesting a hosting platform with more lenient/customizable plugin or whitelisting policies.

Comment: WordPress does support `iframe` embeds out of the box. No matter the hosting provider… Aside from that: Please add real answers (in code). Adding Trinket as new oEmbed provider isn't that hard. **ProTip:** Just add enough data for [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) for your content. That isn't that hard either. And it can be done even without that (just not as extremely easy as with it).

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use Python on WordPress blog via [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) - [`pclose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pclose.php) and [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) functions.

In your specific case I'd recommend to build a shortcode, in order to output your function:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_python_script', 'my_python_script_callback' );

function my_python_script($attributes){

    $py_file_dir = 'YOUR_FILE_PATH';
    $py_file_handle = popen($py_file_dir , 'r');
    $py_file_content = fread($py_file_handle, filesize($py_file_dir));
    pclose($py_file_handle );

    return $py_file_content ;
}
```

After, you can use `[py_file_content]` inside text editor or sidebar, or `do_shortcode('[py_file_content]');` inside theme files.

Additionally make sure that your server got all libs/packages required to perform this.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I want. I don't want to execute a python script on the server side. I want to use the Triket interactive features.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is not possible to do using the online wordpress.com one needs to run the full wordpress.org system and then install the [iframes plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/)